# LINQ compiled query select sum multiple columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, compiled-query

I have a table:

```
ForObjectTypeID (short, PK)
ForObjectID (int, PK)
UserID (int, PK)
Upvote (bool)
ShadowBannedVote (bool)
```

Given an `ObjectTypeID` and `ObjectID`, I wish to return a `Tuple<int, int, int>` where the respective values are:

- **Total Votes:** Total number of records where `ShadowBannedVote == false`
- **Total Upvotes:** Total number of records where `Upvote == true && ShadowBannedVote == false`
- **Total Shadow Banned Votes:** Total number of records where `ShadowBannedVote == true`

It needs to be a single compiled query, not broken into multiple queries.  This is as far as I've gotten, I just can't work out how to perform the sums and counts in the return value.

```
public static readonly Func<DBContext, ObjectType, int, Tuple<int, int, int>> GetTotalVotes = CompiledQuery.Compile(
    (DBContext db, ObjectType forObjectType, int forObjectID) =>
    db.UserVotes.Where(c => c.ForObjectTypeID == (short)forObjectType && c.ForObjectID == forObjectID)
    .Select(c=> new {c.Upvote, c.ShadowBannedVote}).Select(c=> new Tuple<int, int, in>(0, 0, 0)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Will be interested to see if this is possible, but one solution would be:

```
public static readonly Func<DBContext, ObjectType, int, IEnumerable<Tuple<bool, bool>>> GetTotalVotes = CompiledQuery.Compile(
    (DBContext db, ObjectType forObjectType, int forObjectID) =>
    db.UserVotes.Where(c => c.ForObjectTypeID == (short)forObjectType && c.ForObjectID == forObjectID)
    .Select(c=> new Tuple<bool, bool>(c.Upvote, c.ShadowBannedVote)));
```

And then simply work out the numbers in the application logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could try grouping by a constant, summing and taking the result, ie something like

```
  public static readonly Func<DBContext, ObjectType, int, Tuple<int, int, int>> GetTotalVotes = CompiledQuery.Compile(
        (DBContext db, ObjectType forObjectType, int forObjectID) 
   => 
   db.UserVotes
    .Where(c => c.ForObjectTypeID == (short)forObjectType 
             && c.ForObjectID == forObjectID)
    .Select(c => new { c.Upvote, c.ShadowBannedVote })
    .GroupBy(c => 1)
    .Select(c => new Tuple<int, int, int>(
        c.Count(r => !r.ShadowBannedVote), 
        c.Count(r => r.Upvote && !r.ShadowBannedVote), 
        c.Count(r => r.ShadowBannedVote)
    )).Single());
```